# Best way to filter out a subset of document IDs with firebase/firestore JS SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to get some community consensus on how to achieve the following with the Firebase JS SDK (e.g., in React):

Suppose I have a collection `users` and I wanted to paginate `users` that do not have document IDs matching a subset of IDs (O(100-1000)). This subset of excluded IDs is dynamic based on the authenticated user.

It seems the `not in` query only supports up to 10 entries, so this is out of the question.

It also seems it's not possible to fetch all document IDs and filter on the client side, at least not [in the 'firebase' JS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673897/listdocuments-exist-in-google-cloud-firestore-but-not-firebase-npm-module-what).

The only workaround I can think of is to have a document that keeps an array of all `users` document IDs, pull that document locally and perform the filtering/pagination logic locally. The limitation here is that a document can be at most 1MB, so realistically the single document can store at most O(10K) IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has a special bunch of methods for pagination which may be useful for you. Those are called "query cursors".

You can use them to define the start point  `startAt()` or `startAfter()` and to define an end point `endAt()` or `endBefore()`. Additionally, if needed, those can be combined with `limit` method.

I strongly encourage you to check this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). Here you can find a quick video explaining the matter and lot of examples in all popular languages.

Comment: I understand how to use pagination without any filtering, but if I wanted to filtering out a list of 100-1000 document IDs, then paginate afterwards, how would I achieve this with Firebase's API?

Comment: Than I think you will need to restructure the database. Array as you suggested or you can add field with boolean value to every user you want to include and filter over the field.